# C# MemoryCache Implementing with two Items as a Key of LocalCache

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, memorycache

I am using two input parameters(UserID, ProfileID) in SP to retrieve data from DataBase. I would like to store the result in a memoryCache as the result is much static for some duration. I thought to use

string cacheKey = UserID.toString() + "_" + ProfileID.ToString() as a key. It is a pretty straightforward solution if I concat string.

I can use static ConcurrentDictionary as a Cache and Tuple as a cachekey but I do require to expire cache after certain period.

I would like to know any other alternative approaches / thoughts and if any drawbacks of the concatenation of string using as a key.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of the string concatenation for the cache key is good, I would go with that one.

Beware if you want to use a Tuple as a cache key, the ConcurrentDictionary accepts any object to be the cache key but it depends on the "GetHashCode()" object method to actually use it as a key, so you would need to verify if the HashCode generated by your Tuples are consistent otherwise you would have a bug.

The string concatenation is a simpler solution.

Comment: One other option would be to extend the tuple class and override the GetHashCode method to output the string concatenation. This way you would have a class that represents the key and it might make it easier for other developers using the local cache.